# the overflow shows just a gray line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

My website is mostly Single Page Website, but there are some pages that only registered users can enter there. In the first "block" (I can't find other name. I'm speaking about areas in the single page website) there are a button named "Login / register", and when you click on her it shows you a login and registration form.

Because in the registration you should give us a lot of info (first and last name, email, password - twice, recaptcha and checkbox about the terms of use), we designed it like it is a different page, but to make the process faster I decided that it will be on the main page in `position:fixed;`, `overflow:auto;` and `display:none;` and when you'll push the "login / register" button it will change to `display:block;` and it will add `overflow:hidden;` to "body" and "html". Every thing works great, you even can scroll up and down, but the scroll bar itself seems strange.

Here is the JS (jQuery) code:

```
function login(){
$('#loginpopup').css({"display":"block","opacity":"0"});
$('#loginpopup').animate({"opacity":"1"});
$('body').css({"overflow":"hidden"});
$('html').css({"overflow":"hidden"});
return false;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the page with the problem:
[image: look at the arrow :)]

Comment: Can you share a link to the site or some css?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
overflow: visible;
```

instead of

```
overflow: auto;
```

in #loginpopup

Comment: When I'm doing it, the overflow isn't visible (hhh).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the div with class backgroundcolor, which is fixed and has a width and a height of 100%. This div displays over the scrollbar. Get rid of this div and try to put the grey background in the body element.